# Unable to write a polyfill for call function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, polyfills

This is my polyfill for call method

```
Function.prototype.mycall = (obj,...args)=>{
    if(typeof this!="function") throw new Error("mycall can only be used on a function")
    obj.myFunc = this
    obj.myFunc(...args)
    delete obj.myFunc
}
```

And this is my whole script including the polyfill

```
obj = {
    name: "sai",
    age: 25
}

sample = ()=>{
    console.log(`I am ${this.name} and is ${this.age} years old`)
}

Function.prototype.mycall = (obj,...args)=>{
    if(typeof this!="function") throw new Error("mycall can only be used on a function")
    obj.myFunc = this
    obj.myFunc(...args)
    delete obj.myFunc
}


sample.mycall(obj)
```

But when I look at my console, I am getting this error

```
task.js:12 Uncaught Error: mycall can only be used on a function
    at Function.mycall (task.js:12:39)
    at task.js:22:8
Function.mycall @ task.js:12
(anonymous) @ task.js:22
```

Can anyone please help me on why I am getting this error?

Comment: Use regular `function`s rather than arrow functions. Otherwise `this` will refer to the global object for your example.

Comment: Hi @NickParsons, I have tried with regular function too, but still getting the same error

Comment: Did you update both of your arrow functions? I can't reproduce it anymore if you've updated both (maybe share how you're using the regular `function`s).

Comment: Hi @NickParsons, Thank you so much, I have updated both the function to regular functions and it is working fine now